# create map shopping center (for example) on android

Tags: android, dictionary

I Never faced with the task to create a map of the shopping center (for example)
I did a project using a single image as a map,  image was maximum size, but the image quality is not enough. I understand i need many small images. if user scrolling  or zoom or fling map i programmatically change images...

but,I do not know where to begin, please help me your solutions